# How to draw smooth lines in 2D scene with OpenGL without using GL_LINE_SMOOTH?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

Since GL_LINE_SMOOTH is not hardware accelerated, nor supported on all GFX cards, how do you draw smooth lines in 2D mode, which would look as good as with GL_LINE_SMOOTH ?

**Edit2:** My current solution is to draw a line from 2 quads, which fade to zero transparency from edges and the colors in between those 2 quads would be the line color. it works good enough for basic smooth lines rendering and doesnt use texturing and thus is very fast to render.

Comment: Have you ruled out using textured quad, or quad with color gradient? That seems like a possible solution to me, though sounds like Edvard has already covered that territory.

Comment: @Tim, hm, im not sure if only colored quad will work exactly like smooth lines, it might become too sharp... well, i gotta test it.

Comment: @Tim, tested it now, and as i expected, its too sharp (or too blurred), but for my current purposes it works fine! line thickness 1.7 seems to match very well what my current 1.1 thick smooth line does.

Comment: "I dont want to use full screen antialiasing either. What is the most performance wise solution for this?" So, you don't want to use antialiasing, the technique *designed to do exactly what you want*. And you don't want to use shaders. What exactly *do* you want?

Comment: @NicolBolas, i dont want full screen antialiasing because its slow as far as i understand. currently it works good with quads with colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently I am using 2 or 3 quads to do this, it is the simpliest way to do it.

- If line thickness <= 1px, then you need only 2 quads.
- If line thickness > 1px, then you need to add third quad in the middle.
- The fading edge quads thickness must not change if the line thickness >= 1px.

In the image below you can see the quads with blue borders. White color means full opacity and black color means zero opacity (=fully transparent).

[image]

Answer (score 12):

So, you want smooth lines without:

- line smoothing.
- full-screen antialiasing.
- shaders.

Alright.

Your best bet is to use Valve's [Alpha-Tested Magnification technique](http://www.valvesoftware.com/publications/2007/SIGGRAPH2007_AlphaTestedMagnification.pdf). The basic idea, for your needs, is to create a texture that represents the distance from the line, with the center of the texture being a distance of 1.0. This could probably be a 1D texture.

Then using the techniques described in the paper (many of which work with fixed-function, including the antialiased version), draw a quad that represents your lines. Obviously you'll need alpha blending (and thus it isn't order-independent). You use your line width to control the distance at which it becomes the appropriate color, thus allowing you to make narrow or wide lines.

---

Doing this with shaders is virtually identical to the above, except without the texture. Instead of accessing a distance texture, the distance is passed and interpolated from the vertex shader. For the left-edge of the quad, the vertex shader passes 0. For the right edge, it passes 1. You multiply this by 2, subtract 1, and take the absolute value.

That's your distance from the line (the line being the center of the quad). Then just use that distance exactly as Valve's algorithm does.

Comment: i know that technique, but it is not really what im looking for and would take a lot more memory. my current solution with quads with colors is fast and doesnt take up any extra texture memory.

Comment: @Rookie: By "a lot more memory" you mean 4KB (likely the smallest possible allocation for GPUs). You don't need one texture per line, just one texture period. And as stated, it could be a 1D texture; it doesn't have to be particularly large either. A 16x1 `GL_LUMINANCE8` texture would work just fine. Somehow, I don't think you'll miss that 4K of RAM.

Answer (score 3):

Turning on full-screen anti-aliasing and using a quad would be my first choice.

Comment: I think full-screen antialiasing is a bit too overkill for a game which doesnt render anything else antialiased except these lines, which are small part of the game. BTW, Why do you need both, textured quad AND full-screen AA? wouldnt textured quads be sufficient?

Comment: You need both because a quad wouldn't be anti-aliased unless you anti-alias it, and if memory serves (which it could not be), some FSAA-algorithms don't like to antialias lines. As for the FSAA, it's most likely cheaper than using GL_LINE_SMOOTH on cards that don't hardware-accelerate it.

Comment: But wouldnt the quad look like smoothed line if you use a texture which has 1 pixel full opaque and the neighbouring 2 pixels fully transparent? Havent tested yet, but i cant see why not.. because in my texture tests i have drawn a straight line in texture and then rotated the textured quad vertices and the line indeed looks like smoothed line when its rotated, as if it has antialiasing on.

Comment: The problem with that is that a quad that is more than 3 pixels wide will require another texture to avoid the line looking "more smoothed", as well as the 1-pixel problem.

Comment: But is it possible to FSAA only the quads i render? It will become really intensive otherwise, because i would need at least 8x antialiasing, perhaps 16x to make the lines look like they do with `GL_LINE_SMOOTH`.

Comment: Multisampling is enabled by you before rendering. Indeed you can enable it only for the lines.

Comment: @Luca, how? I read some wiki: `You should also call glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE) but in reality this is useless since it is not possible to enable or disable FSAA once you have chosen a FSAA pixelformat. ` http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Multisampling

Comment: @Rookie Wiki is wrong. Read the linked specification of ARB_multisample: is the flag is not enabled, rendering is equivalent to single-sampling. Why a flag should be useless?

Comment: @Rookie: Thank you for pointing out that Wiki page so that I can utterly destroy it. I'm trying to clean out the dark corners of that Wiki, and that's a great place to start.